# Some questions about PHIZ Physical Interaction Zone Kinectv2

Tags: c#, kinect, interaction

I'm here to ask something really stupid: I have some problems writing the code to build a simple PHIZ using Kinect v2.
What I know now is that I have to create a Rectangle (which is the area of the Phiz), select an anchor (maybe a ShoulderLeft or ShoulderRight Joint?), then create a center point using the anchor + an offset. This center is the center of the Rectangle, so basically when the Joint moves, also the phiz does.
Is it all right?

After all that, do I have to check the state of the hand, if it is in the area of the rectangle?

And then what I have to do?

My problem is also the fact that I cannot find any examples online

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, trying to develop a PHIZ using only skeletal joint data. For the moment, I can only suggest to take a look to the [Human Interface Guidelines 2.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/6/676611B4-1982-47A4-A42E-4CF84E1095A8/KinectHIG.2.0.pdf), in particular at page 82 where you can see three views (front, side, top) of the PHIZ. From there, you should easily understand that the PHIZ is not simply a rectangle, but rather it is a sort of thick spherical square.